# Change inner " and (, inconsistent behaviour

Tags: vim

Are there any plugins that patch the inconsistent behaviour of the `c` `i` `<textobject>`?

A common itch for me is the example specified in the title. Given the lines below and the assumption that the cursor is located at the **first character of the line:**

`hello("stuff")` -> `c` `i` `"` -> `hello("")`
`hello('stuff')` -> `c` `i` `'` -> `hello('')`
`hello( stuff )` -> `c` `i` `(`  -> `hello( stuff )`

**First itch:**
`c` `i` `(`/`)` works on none of the lines, unless the cursor is already located **at or inside the parantheses**.

**Second itch:**
`c` `i` `"`/`'` always work on their respective characters, as long as the cursor is located **before or at** the closing tag of the specified character.

**Wrapping up:**

As you see, there is a consistency. I've been letting it slip for some years now, but I wanna straighten it out. You may call me whiny, but working with parameters is something we all do lots of, and while it could be worse, it  could certainly be better. Is there a reason for this behaviour, and how do you get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to prepend `%` to go inside the parentheses first: `%ci(`.

Found at [selecting text inside paranthesis from outside the parenthesis in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803905/selecting-text-inside-paranthesis-from-outside-the-parenthesis-in-vim). Also, see [why ci" and ci( ci{ behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650788/why-ci-and-ci-ci-behave-differently), the same question as yours.

Comment: Okay, but it I don't feel like typing that out all the time. Considering it only jumps to a `()[]{}` on the current line or their match, it seems safe to map `ci(` to `%ci(`. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Sure, you can abbreviate that with a [set of] mapping[s].